# Multiple forms with same Action

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

i have multiple forms with same action, but only one form is displayed at a time, but when i submit a form (any of many)
i want parameters of that specific form only whose submit is called.
like for example:-

```
<form:form action="${contextRoot}/saveName.html"  >
<input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
</form:form  >

<form:form action="${contextRoot}/saveName.html"  >
<input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
</form:form  >
```

for 1st i put name as "Ankit" and for second it is "Felow".
if i click submit for first form i should get "Ankit" from request.getpara()

Comment: they are on a single jsp, it gets submited when i click on submit button.

Comment: If you have one submit button per form (nested within it), it should behave as you expect.

Comment: or you can also change form action using js besides creating mutilple forms one form will serve your purpose